# How to convert varchar to varbinary where each char is followed by a null character?

Tags: sql-server, type-conversion

In SQL Server, the following query

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARBINARY,'1234');
```

returns `0x31323334`.

What can I do in the query in order to return `0x3100320033003400`?

So far, I can do this in C++ and then use it in queries, but I was wondering if there is a cleaner way of doing this (i.e. a way of putting the original string inside the query and letting SQL do the work).

Maybe there is a way of doing the conversion telling SQL that each character in '1234' must be treated as a two byte character. Maybe there is a way splitting and joining. I can't find the way and these are the two approaches I've tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert it to an `nvarchar` and then a `varbinary`, as an `nvarchar` uses double bytes to store characters:

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(VARBINARY(8),CONVERT(nvarchar(4),'1234'));
```

Or, if it's always a literal, just prefix it with an `nvarchar` notation character (`N`).